# How can I check if std::pow will overflow double

Tags: c++, gmp, pow

I have a function that deals with arbitrarily large grids. I need to compute if a grid to the power of another number will fit into a double due to using `std::pow`. If it cannot, I want to take a different branch and use gnu multiprecision library instead of normal.

Is there a quick way to see if:

```
int a = 1024;
int b = 0-10;

if(checkPowFitsDouble(a, b)) {
    long c = static_cast<long>(std::pow(a, b)); //this will only work if b < 6
} else {
    mpz_t c; //yada yada gmp
}
```

I am completely stumped on checkPowFitsDouble; perhaps there is some math trick I don't know  of.

Comment: If you still are going to use e.g. GMP in special cases, why not remove those special cases and *only* use GMP?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I need this function to be very fast. If I can avoid gmp for some cases I need to. The majority of the time gmp will not be used, so I want to take advantage of that.

Comment: You could try logs of maximum doubles and do the right divisions, but that may slow it down

Comment: @doctorlove Thanks! I am developing a better benchmark for this right now.

Comment: You could use any logarithm in theory, base 10, natural, or 17. But the most logical base is 2, and you really don't care about the fractional part of that log. That means you have the very efficient `frexp` function.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to use a long (as in your code sample) or a double (as in your explanations).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sorry for any confusion, I mean to use long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common trick to check whether exponentiations will overflow uses logarithms. The idea is based on these relationships:

`a^b <= m <=> log(a^b) <= log(m) <=> b * log(a) <= log(m) <=> b <= log(m) / log(a)`

For instance,

```
int a = 1024;

for (int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
    if (b * std::log(a) < std::log(std::numeric_limits<long>::max())) {
        long c = std::pow(a, b);
        std::cout << c << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "overflow\n";
}
```

This gives the idea. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks for the great explanation at the top. I clearly need to look into logs more.

Answer (score 4):

Unless it's particularly performance-critical, the suggestion would be to try it and see. If it overflows a double, `std::pow` will return `HUGE_VAL`. Hence something like:

```
double val = std::pow(a, b);
if(val != HUGE_VAL) {
    ...
} else {
    mpz_t c; 
    //...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is performance critical.. Thanks for the suggestion though. If all else fails I might revert to this. Maybe I should look into how std::pow determines this.

Comment: @jett Doubtlessly it lets the hardware determine it (on the usual systems, at least).  On an IEEE machine, `HUGE_VAL` should expand to positive infinity, which is what you will naturally get when calculating `pow` if the values are too large.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for the explanation. I looked in the headers and figured delving into gcc internals would be a bit over my head for this. That makes sense.

Comment: @jett Of course, since the standard requires `errno` to be set, there will be some extra code to check the status flags (and probably to ensure that they are reset before the calculation).

Comment: @jett - even though it's performance-critical, this still seems like the way to go. Unless failures are very common, calculating a logarithm **every** time you need to call `pow` (as the accepted answer proposes) imposes far more overhead than simply calling `pow` and checking for (occasional) failures.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use the reverse functions in the test:

```
if ( std::log( DBL_MAX ) / std::log( a ) < b ) {
    //  std::pow( a, b ) will not overflow...
} else {
}
```

It might be just as good to just do the pow, and see if it
succeeds:

```
errno = 0;
double powab = std::pow( a, b );
if ( errno == 0 ) {
    //  std::pow succeeded (without overflow)
} else {
    //  some error (probably overflow) with std::pow.
}
```

You won't gain much time by just calculating `std::log( a )`.
(`std::log( DBL_MAX )` is, of course, a constant, so only needs
to be calculated once.)

Comment: This is the fastest so far and very succinct. 2 1/2 times faster than checking result of pow from my tests so far.

Comment: So actually.. after a bit of testing it seems that this isn't giving me correct answers? I tried with a large and small number initially, but this accepts a=1024, b=102 as not underflowing (103 it starts saying overflow).

Comment: `pow( 1024., 102. )` doesn't overflow, at least with IEEE double.  (Note that this is basically the same test, mathematically, as that used by Cassio Neri.  I think that written this way, there is less risk of overflow, but I've not analyzed it in detail.)

Comment: @jett - it may be that calculating the log is faster for cases that fail, but that's not the end of the analysis. If failures are rare, the extra log on every calculation ends up costing more than simply checking for failure after the fact, as James's second suggestion does. In general, floating-point experts (which I am not) seem to prefer to run calculations flat out, without checking for errors until the end. That's why we have NaNs: many errors produce NaN, and NaNs persist (in most cases) through the rest of the calculation, so you can check for failure afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

With a logarithm base 10, you can deduce that `std:pow(a, b)` has `log(a^b) = b log a` digits. You can then trivially see if it fits a double, which can fit values up to DBL_MAX.

However, this method performs additional computation than just computing `a^b` once. Measure a version with GMP first and see if checking for overflow actually provides any measurable and reproducible benefits.

EDIT: Ignore this, `std::pow` already returns an appropriate value in case an overflow occurs, so use that.